# Facebook Graph API call only sends to first person specified

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have the following Facebook Graph API call:

```
    FB.ui({
        method: "send",
        to: '123123,456456',
        name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
        link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html'
    }, function(response) {
        // some stuff
    });
```

Whenever it's invoked, my message's only recipient is the user with id `123123`. If I switch the two numbers, the `456456` is the sole recipient.

As far as I can tell, I'm using the API exactly like I'm supposed to, so what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible with the `send` method to specify multiple recipients: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18806

It does look like it can be done with the `apprequests` method, though:

```
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'My message',
        data: {},
        title: "My Title",
        to: [123123, 456456]
    });
```

For my purposes, that's close enough.